# How to change the `application.home` property used in the PlayFramework 2.3?

Tags: playframework-2.3

I've seen [this document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger), but I want to change the `application.home` property with another value.

Are there any ways that I can set the property by command line argument or using `application.conf`. I've tried both but failed.

Please let me know if there are another ways to set it.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us how you tried. Anyway, why would you like to change this path ?

Comment: I think `application.home` is just a map key used in logging setup to hold the root of your project. It is [hardcoded](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L178)